# Reading in from txt file when format changes

Tags: c, assembly, io, scanf, filestream

I'm trying to create an Instruction Set Simulator that reads in assembly and executes the desired action. Each line consists of [address][instruction][input1] and possibly also [input2]

The file I'm reading looks like this:

```
10  MOV R1, 1
11  MOV R2, 10
12  MOV R3, 101
13  ST [R3], R1
14  ADD R1, 1
15  ADD R3, 1
16  CMP R1, R2
17  JE 19
18  JMP 13
19  MOV R2, 5
20  MOV R4, 0
21  MOV R3, 109
22  MOV R1, -1 
23  LD R5, [R3]
24  ADD R3, R1
25  ADD R4, 1
26  CMP R4, R2
27  JE 29
28  JMP 23
29  MOV R3, 120
30  ST [R3], R5
```

and right now I'm trying to parse each line using fscanf:

```
char* buf[100];
    while (fscanf(fptr,"%*s %3s %*s %*s ",buf)==1)
        printf("%s\n", buf);
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
MOV
MOV
ST
ADD
ADD
CMP
JE
13
5
0
109
-1
[R3
R3,
R4,
R4,
29
29
30
```

Could someone explain what's happening and suggest a way to capture each part of the instruction?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you expect that code to do?

Comment: `char* buf[100]` should be `char buf[100]`

Comment: @kaylum I was trying to output just the instruction string i.e. MOV

Comment: Did you re-test with the `buf` issue fixed?

Comment: There aren't 4 fields in each line.  `scanf` is not line oriented, but is reading 4 strings at a time.  Since you want to treat your input as if it is line oriented, you would be better off reading it with `fgets`

Comment: @kaylum yes and I get the same output

Comment: @WilliamPursell I've tried that but I still need to read and save each piece of the line into separate variables and fgets just saves it as a string

Comment: After reading a line with `fgets()`, you parse the line with `scanf()`, checking the result.  In fact, with the line reading regime, you don't care what comes after the opcode (instruction string), so you can use `char opcode[10]; if (sscanf(buf, "%*d %9s", opcode) != 1) { … format error… }`.  One big advantage of using `sscanf()` is that you can make multiple attempts to parse the string with different formats, whereas with direct file I/O, you really can't recover easily from changes in format.

Comment: Also note that trailing spaces in a format string are diabolical if a human will ever type the input.  See [What is the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168)